# How can I solve writing direction?

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

When I press 4,5,6 seriatim, its writing 654 cause the line is always staying same place. I'm using Java & Wicket.

This part is in java class:

```java
     koordinasyonId.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 3097782061837606985L;
                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    if(koordinasyonId.getModelObject()!=null){
                        String koordinasyonIdValue = koordinasyonId.getModelObject();
                        String kordinasyonValue ="";
                        for(int i=0;i<koordinasyonIdValue.length();i++) {
                            String regex = "^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$";
                            if (Pattern.matches(regex,koordinasyonIdValue.charAt(i)+"")) {
                                kordinasyonValue = kordinasyonValue + koordinasyonIdValue.charAt(i);
                            }else if(".".equals(koordinasyonIdValue.charAt(i)+"") || ",".equals(koordinasyonIdValue.charAt(i)+"")){
                                kordinasyonValue = kordinasyonValue + koordinasyonIdValue.charAt(i);
                            }
                        }
                        koordinasyonId.setModelObject(kordinasyonValue);
                        target.add(koordinasyonId);
                    }
                }
            });
```

This part is in html file: (Actually javascript can add to code. So I used in this part)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#koordinasyonId").change(function(){
            let koordinasyonId = document.getElementById("koordinasyonId").value;
            let kordinasyonValue;
            if(koordinasyonId !=null){
                for(var i=0;i<koordinasyonId.length;i++) {
                    if (!isNaN(koordinasyonId.charAt(i))) {
                        kordinasyonValue +=koordinasyonId.charAt(i);
                    } else {
                        if (koordinasyonId.charAt(i).match(".") ||koordinasyonId.charAt(i).match(",") ) {
                            kordinasyonValue +=koordinasyonId.charAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("koordinasyonId").value=koordinasyonValue;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi. It's not clear to me if you are using a Wicket AJAX behavior and also a custom JavaScript code. Also please show the final input you would like to have.

Comment: Hi. There are two files. One of them is **adres.html** and the other one is **adres.java**. This logic belongs to wicket. they must be the same name. This part what I shared is about to regex. I am thinking I have an error this part coding. When I write numbers to coordination input, the writing line is not moving. Normally it should add the end but adds to the top. For example I am press 1 and then 2 it should write 12 but it is 21. Because everytime it is starting at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Using `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` on a `TextField` without any validators and updating the TextField via Ajax in the `onUpdate` method will lead to that behaviour.

The `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` on a `TextField` works as follows:

After the user entered something into the TextField the Behaviour will do an Ajax Request to the server with that input and ask it to validate that input.
If it is valid it will then call the `onUpdate` method, otherwise it will call the `onError` method.

So in your case this will lead to the following:

1. You type 4 into the TextField
2. Wicket will do an Ajax Request and validate if 4 is a valid input
3. As it is a valid input it will call your onUpdate method
4. Inside the onUpdate method you tell wicket to do an ajax refresh on the Input/TextField
5. Because of that Ajax update the curser inside the Input/TextField is reset to the first position

The Solution is most likely that `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` is not the correct way to do whatever you are trying to do. `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` works great for TextFields that have a strict validation, like for example an Input for an IBAN where you can determine the moment the user is done with inputting with certainty because the valid inputs have a fixed length.

If you would tell us what exactly you are trying to archieve here we could probably point you in the right direction of how to archieve that with wicket:

- Are you trying to validate the input?
- Are you trying to prevent the user from entering certain values inside the input/TextField?

Comment: Yes I am trying to prevent the user from entering certain values. User must **number**, **"."** or **","** . And the important thing is I want to check each character one by one. I tried something but it checked when I finished end of the whole input and clicked another place. I dont want to this. If it is possible in html file using with javascript, it can be too.

Comment: I'll update my answer later as I'm currently a little short on time. However one thing I can tell you: I would strongely recommend using the default wicket server side validation (What you said checks only when user finished and sends the data). There are other options doing the validation client side like blocking keypresses with javascript etc. but none of them are secure and can be easily circumvented by knowledgable users who will have no problem disabling everything you try on their client and send your server invalid data. So having some kind of server side validation is a must.